# How to tag pages and layout (not assets) in Liferay

Tags: tags, liferay, liferay-6

I have a Liferay site. I have several pages that needs to be tagged so I can get them in a custom portlet.
I also need to present a page with an alphabetic index of the tagged pages.

I have read documentation and I have seen that Liferay can put a tag or a category only on "assets" (web content, etc.) and not on a page/layout.

Can you suggest me a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about tag/category, these can't be applyed to layout (unfortunately).

The best alternative is to use custom attribute and define the extra fields for the page.

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNAJ2.jpg)

You can read the custom attribute for the page using ExpandoBridge API.
Here an example to read an extra attribute within the theme velocity template.

```
#set ($customField= $layout.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("CustomFieldKey"))
```

Note: Remember to set the permissions on each custom attribute. It's very important!